# Unable to default to LDAP user in WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I joined my wsl2 instance on my desktop to a FreeIPA domain.

I can switch to ldap users normally when logged in by doing `su myusername` or even `sudo -u myusername zsh`.

But I cannot set the default user in `/etc/wsl.conf`.
I tried setting:

```
[user]
default=myusername
```

I also tried putting `sudo -u myusername zsh` in my `.zshrc`, but both give the error

```
<3>WSL (4348) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:357: getpwnam(myusername) failed 0
```

Answer (score 1):

FreeIPA (LDAP) requires a service to be running (sssd or nslcd) which would handle the LDAP connections and queries – but at the time WSL2 performs this part of initialization, it hasn't started any services yet.

(Keep in mind that WSL2 doesn't start the same way as regular VMs do – the WSL2 VM boots into a fixed "system distribution" OS first, then spawns your instance a bit like a Docker container. So it's possible that the system distribution tries to look up the default username in your distro before it has launched systemd.)

Workaround: Duplicate the account information from your FreeIPA domain into the local /etc/passwd (with the same UID and everything), either using `getent passwd myusername >> /etc/passwd` or manually via `useradd`.